# Perform autocomplete with two keys - Material UI with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to autocomplete the input when searched with either of the two values - `title` and `year`. However, it does only work when I search with `title`. When I search with `year`, it does not show any options.

**Sample code**

```
export default function ComboBox() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title || option.year}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

I have created a working example using [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-n7kpc?file=/demo.js)

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to make this work is to make the year part of the option label:

```
/* eslint-disable no-use-before-define */
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";

import { top100Films } from "./movies";
export default function ComboBox() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => `${option.title} (${option.year})`}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit autocomplete title and year]

If you don't want to display the year, but still want to match on it, the other way is to use the `filterOptions` prop to customize the matching:

```
/* eslint-disable no-use-before-define */
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import { createFilterOptions } from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import { top100Films } from "./movies";

const filterOptions = createFilterOptions({
  stringify: (option) => `${option.title} ${option.year}`
});

export default function ComboBox() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      filterOptions={filterOptions}
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit autocomplete title and year]

Related documentation: https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#custom-filter

Comment: Great! I will use `filterOptions`.