# Autocomplete Search Via Another Paramter

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

In below example , -

https://codesandbox.io/s/g5ucdj?file=/demo.tsx

I want to achieve functionality such that , If I have array -

```
const top100Films = [
  { title: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994 },
  { title: 'The Godfather', year: 1972 },
  { title: 'The Godfather: Part II', year: 1994 },]
```

Then , in autocomplete when I search via year , I should get label options for title.
Eg. If I enter year 1994 in search box , I should get two title options for selection -

```
The Shawshank Redemption
The Godfather: Part II
```

I tried changing option -

```
options={top100Films.map((option) => option.year)}
```

But through this I get year as a option which I want title as a option , having year entered in text box.

Comment: Your question was answered here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68305139/13346156

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MUI `createFilterOptions`

```
import { createFilterOptions } from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';
```

Declare filterOptions

```
const filterOptions = createFilterOptions({
  matchFrom: 'any',
  stringify: (option) => option.year.toString(),  //.toString because year is integer
});
```

Then in you Autocomplete tag add this:

```
filterOptions={filterOptions}
```

Codesandbox [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/filter-material-demo-forked-nyf038).

The code is in javascript, you can change to typescript accordingly. For typescript follow this [link](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#Filter.tsx)

Answer (score 1):

As I see you are using React js,
so I will suggest you, to use React-select for better functionality

1. Add Package using "npm i --save react-select".
2. Import as a Component
3. use <Select {data}/> in jsx format
4. Add json data to {data}.

Reference documantion: React-select npm https://react-select.com/home

Everything is perfectly documented

Comment: This should be posted as a comment and not an answer as it doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: @Aniket - this is material ui in react | react madhala material ui aahe he