# ReactJS - Material UI - Symbol Autocomplete with Suggestions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am wondering if there is any easy way to use either Material-UI autocomplete or any other llibrary which offers autocomplete options which look as following:

- Step one -> User enter following symbol in an input field: %
- Step two -> Autocomplete shows as suggestion: percent

My idea would be to create an Object with symbols and their value.
On ea. entered Symbol, check the Object if entered symbol matches any symbol in the Object, if so, offer an suggestion.

Comment: Its possible using MaterialUI autocomplete. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72259158/13405106), hope this does the work

Comment: sadly not, that simply shows that you can inject your own rules, but those rules are not heading towards what i would like to achieve

Comment: You want to show `Percent` menu in text when user writes `%`. This can be done as shown in the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/filter-material-demo-forked-nyf038), which is mentioned is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72254522/autocomplete-search-via-another-paramter/72259158#72259158). In the example, just change `year` value to `"%"`, then search using symbol. You will get the suggestion in text form